# Attaching an EFS volume to Fargate?

Tags: terraform, aws-fargate, amazon-efs

I know this question has been asked before, and I've seen several of the SO responses and read the AWS docs on the subject... I have a terraform module that, in part, builds out an ECS service, cluster, task, and Fargate container:

```
###############################################################################
#### EFS for added stoage
#### TODO: remove in favor of larger ephmemeral storage when terraform supports it
###############################################################################
resource "aws_efs_file_system" "test" {
  creation_token = var.fargate_container_name

  tags = {
    Name = "test"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_access_point" "test" {
  file_system_id = aws_efs_file_system.test.id
  root_directory {
    path = "/"
  }
}

resource "aws_efs_mount_target" "test" {
  count           = 3
  file_system_id  = aws_efs_file_system.test.id
  subnet_id       = local.directory_subnet_ids[count.index]
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.test_ecs.id]
}

###############################################################################
#### ECS Task and Service
###############################################################################
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "test" {
  family                   = "test"
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  cpu                      = var.test_cpu_limit
  memory                   = var.test_memory_limit
  container_definitions    = <<JSON
[
      {
          "name": "test",
          "image": "${var.test_image_registry_repo_and_image_name}",
          "memory": ${var.test_memory_limit},
          "cpu": ${var.test_cpu_limit},
          "essential": true,
          "portMappings": [
            {
              "containerPort": 7001,
              "hostPort": 7001,
              "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
              "containerPort": 7002,
              "hostPort": 7002,
              "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
              "containerPort": 9001,
              "hostPort": 9001,
              "protocol": "tcp"
            },
            {
              "containerPort": 9002,
              "hostPort": 9002,
              "protocol": "tcp"
            }
          ],
          "logConfiguration": {
              "logDriver": "awslogs",
              "options": {
                  "awslogs-group": "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.test_ecs.name}",
                  "awslogs-region": "${data.aws_region.main.name}",
                  "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
              }
          },
          "linuxParameters": {
            "initProcessEnabled": true
          },
          "mountPoints": [
          {
            "containerPath": "/",
            "sourceVolume": "${var.fargate_container_name}"
          }
        ]
      }
]
JSON
  volume {
    name = var.fargate_container_name

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id          = aws_efs_file_system.test.id
      transit_encryption      = "ENABLED"
      transit_encryption_port = 2049
      authorization_config {
        access_point_id = aws_efs_access_point.test.id
        iam             = "ENABLED"
      }
    }
  }

  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  # The role used by ECS to pull images and the like.
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.test_ecs_execution.arn
  task_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.test_task_ecs.arn

  tags = merge(
    local.tags, {
      "Name" = "test"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "test" {
  name                   = "test"
  cluster                = aws_ecs_cluster.test.id
  task_definition        = aws_ecs_task_definition.test.arn
  desired_count          = var.test_desired_count
  enable_execute_command = true
  platform_version       = "1.4.0"

  # service_registries {
  #   registry_arn   = aws_service_discovery_service.test.arn
  #   container_name = "test"
  # }

  capacity_provider_strategy {
    base              = var.fargate_capacity_provider_base_value
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE"
    weight            = var.fargate_capacity_provider_weight_value
  }

  capacity_provider_strategy {
    base              = var.fargate_spot_capacity_provider_base_value
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE_SPOT"
    weight            = var.fargate_spot_capacity_provider_weight_value
  }

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.test_ecs.id]
    subnets         = local.directory_subnet_ids
  }

  tags = merge(
    local.tags, {
      "Name" = "test"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_security_group" "test_ecs" {
  name_prefix = "test-ecs"
  description = "Allow strict inbound access to ECS Tasks"
  vpc_id      = data.aws_vpc.primary.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 2049
    to_port     = 2049
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [data.aws_vpc.primary.cidr_block]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 7001
    to_port     = 7002
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 9001
    to_port     = 9002
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = merge(
    local.tags, {
      "Name" = "test-ecs"
    }
  )
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "test_task_ecs" {
  name                 = "EST"
  description          = "Test."
  permissions_boundary = data.aws_iam_policy.role_permissions_boundary.arn
  assume_role_policy   = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

I've explicitly set the Fargate version in the service, I saw some other SO user answered stating that the VPC needed to have DNS hostnames and resolution set to true -- they are. I'm still getting the error:

container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: process_linux.go:459: container init caused: rootfs_linux.go:71: creating device nodes caused: errno 524

It seems to be connected to "mountPoints" block in the container definition, as removing it will at least start the container, but it will not mount the EFS volume.

EDIT: Added ECS Task role

EDIT 2: Adding role permissions boundary:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "UseServices",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "organizations:DescribeOrganization",
                "cloudshell:*",
                "compute-optimizer:*",
                "amplify:*",
                "appmesh:*",
                "appmesh-preview:*",
                "appconfig:*",
                "appflow:*",
                "clouddirectory:*",
                "datapipeline:*",
                "dms:*",
                "dbqms:*",
                "devicefarm:*",
                "devops-guru:*",
                "ds:*",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "imagebuilder:*",
                "ec2-instance-connect:*",
                "ecr-public:*",
                "forecast:*",
                "honeycode:*",
                "proton:*",
                "rds-db:*",
                "rds-data:*",
                "access-analyzer:*",
                "ce:*",
                "cur:*",
                "health:*",
                "pricing:*",
                "ram:Get*",
                "ram:List*",
                "servicequotas:*",
                "ssm:*",
                "ssmmessages:*",
                "support:*",
                "tag:*",
                "cloudfront:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "ecs:*",
                "ecr:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "synthetics:*",
                "servicequotas:*",
                "apigateway:*",
                "rds:*",
                "secretsmanager:*",
                "route53:*",
                "acm:*",
                "resource-groups:*",
                "servicediscovery:*",
                "application-autoscaling:*",
                "ec2messages:*",
                "trustedadvisor:*",
                "cloud9:*",
                "codeartifact:*",
                "codebuild:*",
                "codecommit:*",
                "codedeploy:*",
                "codepipeline:*",
                "codestar:*",
                "codestar-connections:*",
                "codestar-notifications:*",
                "cognito-identity:*",
                "cognito-idp:*",
                "cognito-sync:*",
                "dynamodb:*",
                "eks:*",
                "emr-containers:*",
                "elasticache:*",
                "elasticbeanstalk:*",
                "elasticfilesystem:*",
                "firehose:*",
                "kafka:*",
                "kinesis:*",
                "kinesisanalytics:*",
                "serverlessrepo:*",
                "sqs:*",
                "xray:*",
                "workspaces:*",
                "wam:*",
                "appsync:*",
                "athena:*",
                "batch:*",
                "states:*",
                "backup:*",
                "backup-storage:*",
                "es:*",
                "glue:*",
                "databrew:*",
                "lightsail:*",
                "timestream:*",
                "schemas:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "sts:AssumeRole",
                "sts:TagSession",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "lambda:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:*",
                "events:*",
                "kms:*",
                "logs:*",
                "cloudtrail:*",
                "iam:ListAccountAliases"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowServiceLinkedRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole",
                "iam:GetServiceLinkedRoleDeletionStatus",
                "iam:UpdateRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowPolicy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:CreatePolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:ListPolicyVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:policy/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:DeleteRole",
                "iam:TagRole",
                "iam:UpdateRoleDescription",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfilesForRole",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:UpdateAssumeRolePolicy",
                "iam:PassRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:role/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowWriteRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateRole",
                "iam:DeleteRolePolicy",
                "iam:AttachRolePolicy",
                "iam:DetachRolePolicy",
                "iam:PutRolePermissionsBoundary",
                "iam:PutRolePolicy",
                "iam:UpdateRole",
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "iam:PermissionsBoundary": "arn:aws:iam::835718480179:policy/CuriPipelineAdministratorAccessPermBoundaries"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowWriteInstanceProfile",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:AddRoleToInstanceProfile",
                "iam:CreateInstanceProfile",
                "iam:DeleteInstanceProfile",
                "iam:GetInstanceProfile",
                "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
                "iam:RemoveRoleFromInstanceProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:instance-profile/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "DenyIamActions",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:*OpenIDConnect*",
                "iam:*SAMLProvider*",
                "iam:*User*",
                "iam:*Group*",
                "iam:*AccessKey*",
                "iam:*Password*",
                "iam:CreateAccountAliases",
                "iam:DeleteAccountAliases",
                "iam:*LoginProfile*",
                "iam:*ServiceSpecificCredential*",
                "iam:*MFADevice*",
                "iam:*CredentialReport*",
                "iam:*OrganizationsAccessReport*",
                "iam:*SecurityTokenServicePreferences*",
                "iam:GetAccountAuthorizationDetails",
                "iam:GetAccountSummary"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "NoBoundaryPolicyEdit",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreatePolicyVersion",
                "iam:DeletePolicy",
                "iam:DeletePolicyVersion",
                "iam:SetDefaultPolicyVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::835718480179:policy/CuriPipelineAdministratorAccessPermBoundaries"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "NoSelfRoleEdit",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "iam:Add*",
                "iam:Attach*",
                "iam:Change*",
                "iam:Create*",
                "iam:Delete*",
                "iam:Deactivate*",
                "iam:Detach*",
                "iam:Enable*",
                "iam:Update*",
                "iam:Put*",
                "iam:Remove*",
                "iam:Reset*",
                "iam:Tag*",
                "iam:Untag*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::835718480179:role/CuriPipelineAdministratorAccess"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since you are using IAM auth for your EFS, what is your task role?

Comment: @Marcin: added task role to code.

Comment: Where is the rest of your role? What is this permission boundary?

Comment: @Marcin: added. I do see elasticfilesystem:*; I tried to remove the IAM auth -- same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole problem had nothing to do with AWS, but the server I am running (weblogic) failed to start because I was trying to mount EFS in /, which cannot be done as it would overlay many critical startup and credential files. If I had the whole filesystem already on EFS (which I did not, I used a blank filesystem), then this likely would have been fine. I mounted it successfully to a lower subdirectory and the container spun up and is running.